# Flink job cannot fetch EC2 IAM Role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-flink, amazon-iam, presto

I am trying to use a aws s3 Bucket as a file Source for my flink streaming.

Therefore I need to set a IAM Role or AWS credentials [flink 1.13 docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/deployment/filesystems/s3/#configure-access-credentials).

Unfortunately I always get an error which says that he cannot fetch the security details at http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/. If I make a curl on the flink worker with this URL I get the rolename as a response. When I add the rolename to the curl [http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/{role_name}](http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/%7Brole_name%7D) I **can** get the temporary credentials from the role.

So here is my question: How can I tell flink which role it shall use? I don't see any properties where I can tell flink the name of the IAM Role. Or am I doing something wrong? 
Locally it works fine with setting the aws credentials, but I want to solve this with IAM Roles for the EC2 instances because it is much more beautiful. I cannot find any description to this process in neither the [flink 1.13 docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/deployment/filesystems/s3/#configure-access-credentials) or the [presto docs](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.187/connector/hive.html#amazon-s3-configuration).

I use *flink 1.13* and the *s3-presto* library.

```
2021-05-06 10:17:22,910 WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                    [] - Source: Custom File Source (1/1)#1 (9bb80a7b4f4aafd734c926e90b02d318) switched from RUNNING to FAILED with failure cause: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: The requested metadata is not found at http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/
at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.doReadResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:89)
at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.doReadResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:70)
at com.amazonaws.internal.InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher.readResource(InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher.java:75)
at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.readResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:66)
at com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceMetadataServiceCredentialsFetcher.getCredentialsEndpoint(InstanceMetadataServiceCredentialsFetcher.java:58)
at com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceMetadataServiceCredentialsFetcher.getCredentialsResponse(InstanceMetadataServiceCredentialsFetcher.java:46)
at com.amazonaws.auth.BaseCredentialsFetcher.fetchCredentials(BaseCredentialsFetcher.java:112)
at com.amazonaws.auth.BaseCredentialsFetcher.getCredentials(BaseCredentialsFetcher.java:68)
at com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.java:166)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.getCredentialsFromContext(AmazonHttpClient.java:1257)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.runBeforeRequestHandlers(AmazonHttpClient.java:833)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:783)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:704)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:550)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:530)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5062)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getBucketRegionViaHeadRequest(AmazonS3Client.java:5850)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.fetchRegionFromCache(AmazonS3Client.java:5823)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5046)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5008)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:1338)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:1312)
at com.facebook.presto.hive.s3.PrestoS3FileSystem.lambda$getS3ObjectMetadata$2(PrestoS3FileSystem.java:563)
at com.facebook.presto.hive.RetryDriver.run(RetryDriver.java:138)
at com.facebook.presto.hive.s3.PrestoS3FileSystem.getS3ObjectMetadata(PrestoS3FileSystem.java:560)
at com.facebook.presto.hive.s3.PrestoS3FileSystem.getFileStatus(PrestoS3FileSystem.java:311)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1734)
at org.apache.flink.fs.s3presto.common.HadoopFileSystem.exists(HadoopFileSystem.java:165)
at org.apache.flink.core.fs.PluginFileSystemFactory$ClassLoaderFixingFileSystem.exists(PluginFileSystemFactory.java:148)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.ContinuousFileMonitoringFunction.run(ContinuousFileMonitoringFunction.java:215)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:110)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:66)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask$LegacySourceFunctionThread.run(SourceStreamTask.java:269)
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay I am just stupid. The request of the IAM Role was taking place in the flink manager and not the flink worker.
I simply added the IAM Role to the EC2 Instance of the flink Manager and it worked!